# Why securityAdmin does not have enough permission?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, security

I am a server securityAdmin.

[image]

The securityAdmin role should be treated as equivalent to the sysadmin role, according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles), but I failed to do below 2 things

1. make myself as sysAdmin
2. grant myself **write** right to a database. (currently in db_denydatawriter role )

[image]

[image]

Did I miss anything?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

per RDFozz's comment, I was able to add a new 'dummy' login, but failed to set this login as a user of this database.

[image]

**UPDATE 2 -- final script that works!**

[sepupic's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199494/116897) is great! following his instruction, here is the SQL.

first, use myLogin to create a new super_user.

```
CREATE LOGIN [super_login] WITH PASSWORD=N'yourPassword'
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [super_login]
Grant IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::[sa] TO [super_login]
```

then login with the super_login, run this.

```
Execute as login = 'sa'
  ALTER ROLE [db_denydatawriter] DROP MEMBER [mylogin]
  --ALTER ROLE [db_owner] add MEMBER [mylogin]
  ALTER server ROLE [sysadmin] add MEMBER [mylogin]
Revert
```

Comment: The link you included specifies that the reason securityadmin should be treated like sysadmin is that securityadmin can grant access to the server, and to certain roles with respect to databases. So, depending on the permissions granted the securityadmin user, they might (for instance) be able to create a new user, and grant that user dbo access to a database. This does not mean securityadmins can do *everything* sysadmins can do.

Comment: thanks @RDFozz, I created a new login, but failed to add it as a db's user. (I was able to add it to any other databases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The securityAdmin role should be treated as equivalent to the sysadmin
>   role, according to Microsoft, but I failed to do below 2 things
>
> 1. make myself as sysAdmin
> 2. grant myself write right to a database. (currently in
>      db_datadenywrite role )

All the above is wrong. `Secutiry admin` **is not** `sysadmin`, if it was so for what purpose 2 **different** server roles were created?

`Security admin` has these 3 permissions at server level:

- `CONNECT SQL`
- `ALTER ANY LOGIN`
- `VIEW ANY DATABASE`

`CONNECT SQL` and `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permissions are granted to `public`, so there is only one additional permission, `ALTER ANY LOGIN`.

At the database level this role adds you the possibility to grant permissions to other users, but you don't have `alter any user` / `alter any role`, so you cannot add yourself or any other user to database role.

The phrase

> The ability to grant access to the Database Engine and to configure
>   user permissions allows the security admin to assign most server
>   permissions. The securityadmin role should be treated as equivalent to
>   the sysadmin role.

in my opinion means the following: `security admin` can elevate his permissions to `sysadmin` in some way.

I can give you an idea of this "way".

If you are `security admin` you can create SQL Server login ( I'll call him `super_login`) and grant him `CONTROL SERVER` permission.

The next step is to log in as `super_login` and give all the permissions you want to **your** login. You can make yourself `db_owner` of the database where now you are `db_datadenywriter`, or drop yourself from `db_datadenywriter` or merely add your login to `sysadmin` fixed server role.